# Why is deshake background green and how do I make it black?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, rgb, yuv

FFmpeg version: *4.3.2-2021-02-27-full_build-www.gyan.dev*, Windows

When I apply the *deshake* filter to a video, e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "deshake=rx=64:ry=64:edge=blank" -c:v h264_qsv output.mp4
```

Even though I specify `edge=blank`, the background ends up being a dark green, e.g.:

[image]

Why is that happening? How do I make it be black?

The [filter docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#deshake) say:

> `edge`
>
> Specify how to generate pixels to fill blanks at the edge of the frame. Available values are:
>
> `‘blank, 0’` - Fill zeroes at blank locations
>
> ...

My interpretation of "fill zeroes" was black, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

---

I think [the answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1662495/245945) regarding YUV 0's being green is on the right track, but `deshake` seems to be forcing `yuv444p` and I'm not sure why.

For example, an attempt to convert to RGB, using `showinfo` to print the formats along the way (line breaks for clarity):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 
       -vf "showinfo=checksum=false,
            format=rgb24,
            showinfo=checksum=false,
            deshake=edge=blank,
            showinfo=checksum=false" 
       -f null -
```

Outputs (abbreviated):

```
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000010c55ab2f40] n:  22 pts:     44 pts_time:0.733333 pos:   348574 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:1280x720 i:P iskey:0 type:P
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0000010c55ab2f40] color_range:unknown color_space:unknown color_primaries:unknown color_trc:unknown
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0000010c5860d500] n:  22 pts:     44 pts_time:0.733333 pos:   348574 fmt:rgb24 sar:0/1 s:1280x720 i:P iskey:0 type:P
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0000010c5860d500] color_range:tv color_space:unknown color_primaries:unknown color_trc:unknown
[Parsed_showinfo_4 @ 0000010c5861df80] n:  22 pts:     44 pts_time:0.733333 pos:   348574 fmt:yuv444p sar:0/1 s:1280x720 i:P iskey:0 type:P
[Parsed_showinfo_4 @ 0000010c5861df80] color_range:tv color_space:unknown color_primaries:unknown color_trc:unknown
```

In other words, it's doing this:

```
input.mp4
    ↓  [yuv420p]
format=rgb24
    ↓  [rgb24]
deshake
    ↓  [yuv444p]   <--- ?????????
encoder / output
```

I'm not sure why that's happening. Just to confirm it wasn't something to do with the output format propagating backwards, I also tested this and verified it has the same issues (GIF output uses rgb8):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "format=rgb8,deshake=edge=blank" -c:v gif output.gif
```

Also, along those lines, adding `format=rgb24` again *after* `deshake` yields similarly confusing results:

```
input.mp4
    ↓  [yuv420p]
format=rgb24
    ↓  [rgb24]
deshake
    ↓  [yuv444p]   <--- ?????????
format=rgb24
    ↓  [rgb24]
encoder / output
```

I experimented a bit with the `+` option to `-pix_fmt` but couldn't get that working either: It's documented as disabling automatic conversions in filters, but I guess `format` filters also count as "automatic conversion" because it prevents those all from functioning as well.

Comment: PS: The input video I've been testing on was downloaded from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iy6MB065Dno), if it's useful (although I have the same result with all inputs tested). - Note I am not the author.

Comment: Maybe try a colorkey filter with a black background image

Answer (score 1):

in YUV color model a value of 0 for U and V results in Green color

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV

you could try a color format that has 0 as black

without having tested it myself (and without knowing your pixel format), try something like
`-vf "format=rgb24,deshake=rx=64:ry=64:edge=blank"`

Comment: Ok; you're definitely on to something I think. Can confirm input format is `yuvj420p` (which I probably shouldn't be using anyways, swscaler is complaining about deprecated formats) and the 0 -> green checks out. However, that `format=rgb24` filter doesn't seem quite correct but I just did a quick test (a very non-minimal test too, in a more complex filter graph, so that could be making it weird too). I'm going to investigate a little more deeply into the color formats here and I'll let you know what I find. Thanks a *lot*, super helpful insight.

Comment: Still no luck; I added details about this to the question.

Comment: you can artificially force the green color to be replaced with black
-vf "split[a][b];[a]deshake=rx=64:ry=64:edge=blank,colorkey=0x008000:blend=0:similarity=.05[a];[b]drawbox=color=black:t=fill[b];[b][a]overlay" but thats not ideal

Answer (score 0):

you could use vidstabdetect/transform instead of deshake

first run

`ffmpeg -i input -vf vidstabdetect=shakiness=10:result=info.trf -f null -`

and then run

`ffplay -i input -vf vidstabtransform=input=info.trf:crop=black`

(or an equivalent ffmpeg command with an output file)
and play with the parameters